# How to explain this incomprehensible result of IEnumerable.Where() clause?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have the following test code:

```
var ext = ".xml";
var xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => ext.Equals(Path.GetExtension(s)));
var xmlFiles2 = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var xmlFiles3 = xmlFiles2.Where(s => ext.Equals(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

`path` in this case leads to a folder containing one XML file. Setting a break point yields the following results:

- `xmlFiles` is an empty `IEnumerable<string>`
- `xmlFiles2` is a `string[]`containing one member with the path to the file in the folder
- `xmlFiles3` is the same as xmlFiles
- Evaluating the expression `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => ext.Equals(Path.GetExtension(s)))` directly in the VS Watch-Window is actually what confuses me. After the program hits the breakpoint, the resulting value is "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated". Pressing the button to refresh the evaluation yields the expected result, which is an `IEnumerable<string>` containing one member with the path to my XML-file. Why is this different from `xmlFiles` ??

**Edit**

As requested, here are screenshots of the watch window.

Before re-evaluation

[image]

After re-evaluation

[image]

Comment: would be helpful if you provide screenshot of watch window. also no need in `Where` clause, since you can simply rewrite `"*.*"` to `"*.xml"`

Comment: @YegorAndrosov I added screenshots. It's still curious, why the re-evaluation yields a different result than the actual code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your point is weird to me, as 1. I tested with both versions, as I suspected this and 2. if I check in the above code for example `Path.GetExtension(xmlFiles2[0])`, the resulting value is ".xml", so the extension with the dot.

Comment: As an aside, you should really *consider* `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks for the suggestion. So, this is actually a timing issue (evaluation before full population)?

Comment: Are the IEnumerables really empty? From what you show in the screenshots, you simply haven't enumerated them yet

Comment: @voidengine can you elaborate? How would I change my code?

Comment: To enumerate the IEnumerable, open its "Results view" in the watch window. Or, in code force the enumeration by accessing the result, e.g. add a `ToArray()`

Comment: @voidengine You, Sir, are very correct! :)
This answered my question, thanks a lot!

Comment: @RolandDeschain I'll add this as an answer, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch window doesn't actually show that `xmlFiles` and `xmlFiles3` are empty. It shows that they haven't been enumerated yet. In such case the watch window won't show any values (as there's no way to know what the iterator will produce), only the message "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable".

To show the values provided by the IEnumerable, simply expand the "Results View".

In code, you'll force the enumeration by accessing the values of the `IEnumerable` typically by iterating over it in a `foreach` or by calling `ToArray()` or `ToList()` on it.